# Switching between swiping activities and maintaining data

Tags: java, android

I have 3 activities Add_Case1 , Add_Case2 and Add_Case3.
I am using Swipe Gesture to switch back and forth between them.

My problem is: I'm on `Add_Case1` I fill in some data and then swipe to the `Add_Case2` activity now fill in the data in `Add_Case2` and swipe to the `Add_Case3` activity  now, if I swipe back to go to `Add_Case1` or `Add_Case2`, I can see that the data which I filled in persists. But when I now again swipe from `Add_Case1` to `Add_Case2` or `Add_Case3`. The data has been lost .

I tried using  `android:launchMode="singleTop"` ,`android:launchMode="singleTask"` , even onSaveInstanceState but it's not working.
Here is the relevant code for the files

Add_Case1

```
            public class Add_case1 extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener{
                private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
                public Spinner et5;
                public EditText et1,et2,et3,et4;
                public static String s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6[];        //variables defined as static so that it can be used in
                                                           //  Add_case3.java directly
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    Log.d("Oncreate()","Add Case 1");
                    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
                    {
                        Log.d("Oncreate() sis","Add Case 1");
                        et1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("et1"));
                        et2.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("et2"));
                        et3.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("et3"));
                        et4.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("et4"));
                    }
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_case);
                    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    et4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);          
                    et5=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.case_stage);
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                            R.array.case_stages, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    et5.setAdapter(adapter);
                    et5.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
                    {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                                    int pos, long arg3)
                            {
                                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                                s6=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.case_stages);
                                s5=s6[index];
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                    });
                    // Detect touched area
                    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
                    super.onNewIntent(intent);
                    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
                    setIntent(intent);
                }



        @Override
            protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
                Log.d("OnSaveInstanceState()","Add Case 1");
                savedInstanceState.putString("et1", et1.getText().toString());
                savedInstanceState.putString("et2", et2.getText().toString());
                savedInstanceState.putString("et3", et3.getText().toString());
                savedInstanceState.putString("et4", et4.getText().toString());

            }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
            // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
             this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
           return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
        }
        @Override
         public void onSwipe(int direction) {
            //assigning the values entered by user in static data members
            s1=et1.getText().toString();
            s2=et2.getText().toString();
            s3=et3.getText().toString();
            s4=et4.getText().toString();
              switch (direction) {

          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT : 
              Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case2");
              openStartingPoint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
              openStartingPoint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                //finish();
             //   break;     
          }
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

        @Override
        public void onDoubleTap() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

Add_Case2

```
        public class Add_case2 extends FragmentActivity implements SimpleGestureListener{
                private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
                public EditText et6,et7,et8;
                DateDialogFragment fragnd,fragpd;
                Calendar nownd,nowpd;
                TextView date,date_pr;
                int a;
                public static String s6,s7,s8,s9,s10; //static strings for direct and easy use in Add_case3.java
            @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    Log.d("Oncreate()","Add Case 2");
                    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
                    {
                        Log.d("Oncreate() sis","Add Case 2");
                        et6.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("et6"));
                        et7.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("et7"));
                        et8.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("et8"));

                    }
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_case2);
                    et6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    et7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    et8=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);   
                    nownd = Calendar.getInstance();
                    nowpd=nownd;
                    date_pr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                    date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
                    date_pr.setPaintFlags(date_pr.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
                    date.setPaintFlags(date.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
                    date_pr.setText(String.valueOf(nownd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))+"-"+String.valueOf(nownd.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(nownd.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
                    date.setText(String.valueOf(nownd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))+"-"+String.valueOf(nowpd.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(nowpd.get(Calendar.YEAR)));

                    date_pr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            a=1;
                            showDialog();   
                        }
                    });

                    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(View v){
                            a=2;
                            showDialog();
                        }

                    });

                    // Detect touched area
                    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
            }
            public void showDialog() {
                if(a==1)
                {
                    fragnd = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(this, new DateDialogFragmentListener(){
                    public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day){
                        date_pr.setText(String.valueOf(day)+"-"+String.valueOf(month+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(year));
                        nownd.set(year, month, day);
                    //  s6=String.valueOf(day)+"-"+String.valueOf(month+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(year);
                        Log.d("date picker","Showing up from tv1 next date ="+s6);
                    }
                }, nownd);
                fragnd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DateDialogFragment");
                }
                else if(a==2)
                {
                    fragpd = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(this, new DateDialogFragmentListener(){
                        public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day){

                            date.setText(String.valueOf(day)+"-"+String.valueOf(month+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(year));
                            nowpd.set(year, month, day);
                        //  s7=String.valueOf(day)+"-"+String.valueOf(month)+"-"+String.valueOf(year);
                            Log.d("date picker","Showing up from textView s7 ="+s7);                    }
                    }, nowpd);
                    fragpd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DateDialogFragment");
                }

            }
            public interface DateDialogFragmentListener{
                //this interface is a listener between the Date Dialog fragment and the activity to update the textview's date
                public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
                super.onNewIntent(intent);
                // getIntent() should always return the most recent
                setIntent(intent);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
                Log.d("OnSaveInstanceState()","Add Case 2");
                savedInstanceState.putString("et6", et6.getText().toString());
                savedInstanceState.putString("et7", et7.getText().toString());
                savedInstanceState.putString("et8", et8.getText().toString());

            }  
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
            // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
             this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
           return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
        }
        @Override
         public void onSwipe(int direction) {
            s6= date_pr.getText().toString();
            s7= date.getText().toString();
            s8=et8.getText().toString();   //stores remarks
            s9=et6.getText().toString();   //stores fee settled
            s10=et7.getText().toString();  //stores fee paid

          switch (direction) {

          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : 
              Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case1");
              openStartingPoint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
              openStartingPoint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                //finish();
                                                   break;
          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  
             Intent openStartingPoint2=new Intent("app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case3");
             openStartingPoint2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
             openStartingPoint2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             startActivity(openStartingPoint2);
            //finish();
                                               break;

          }
        }

         @Override
         public void onDoubleTap() {

         }

      }
```

Add_Case3

```
        public class Add_case3 extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener{
                private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
                Button but;
                EditText et9,et10,et11;



            @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_case3);
                    final DatabaseHandler dbs = new DatabaseHandler(this);
                    but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Sumit);
                    et9=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    et10=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    et11=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);


                    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //inserting Add_case1 data in case_info table
                            Log.d("Insert case: ", "Inserting case..");
                            dbs.addCase(new Case(Add_case1.s1,Add_case1.s2,Add_case1.s3,Add_case1.s4,Add_case1.s5));

                            //inserting Add_case2 data in date_info table
                            Log.d("Insert date: ", "Inserting date..");             
                            dbs.addDate(new Date(Add_case1.s2,Add_case2.s6,Add_case2.s7,Add_case2.s9,Add_case2.s10,Add_case2.s8));

                            //inserting Add_case3 data in client_info table
                            Log.d("Insert client: ", "Inserting client..");
                            dbs.addClient(new Client(Add_case1.s2,et9.getText().toString(),et10.getText().toString(),et11.getText().toString())); 
                            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting finish..");


                            Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("app.schedulawyer.com.View");
                            Log.d("view: ", "starting activity view ..");
                            startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                            finish();

                        }
                    });

                    // Detect touched area
                    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
                super.onNewIntent(intent);
                // getIntent() should always return the most recent
                setIntent(intent);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
            // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
             this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
           return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
        }
        @Override
         public void onSwipe(int direction) {

          switch (direction) {

          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT :  
              Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case2");
              openStartingPoint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
              openStartingPoint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                //finish();
                                                         break;

          }
         //  CharSequence str="";
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onDoubleTap() {
          //  Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

      }
```

Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case1"
        android:label="Add Case"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case1" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case2"
        android:label="Add Case"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case2" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case3"
        android:label="Add Case"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="app.schedulawyer.com.Add_case3" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change the way you do this completely. If you really want to use Activity's you can save the data to disk or database or if it is small SharedPreferences. This way you can get the data whenever you want.

But I think you should use 1 `Activity`, 1 `ViewPager` in it and 3 `Fragments` in that `ViewPager`.

You can find a tutorial below:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

And you can also get the code ready when you open a new Activity just use "New Blank Activity" and then select "Swipe Views + Title Strip" as a Navigation Type. After that you will have the behavior I descripe above and then you can delete Title Strip if you want to.

Comment: That helped a lot.
Please see if you could help me with this too.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/22182367/3377639

Answer (score 1):

yes @tasomaniac is right, using view pager is better idea.
find some good tutorial at http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Used the ViewPagerIndicator as you said .
Please see if you could help me with this too.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/22182367/3377639