# Notification started from AlarmManager keeps repeating again

Tags: android

When I set a Notification on a particular date and time chosen from a DatePicker and a TimePicker, The notification appears on the correct time but after I cancel it, it reappears after some time.
I have tried `setAutoCancel(true)` and `Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` but they don't seem to work.

here is the code-snippet where I'm setting alarm

```
 if(item.getTitle().equals("Add Reminder"))
    {
        Log.d("REMINDER", "Show Time Picker Entered from Decided Case");
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.date_time_layout);

        dialog.setTitle("Choose Date and Time");

        dialog.show();
        Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.alarm_set);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
                TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       //for using this you need to import java.util.Calendar;

                // add minutes to the calendar object
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, dp.getMonth());
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, dp.getYear());               
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dp.getDayOfMonth());
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.getCurrentMinute());
                //cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                 //cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                // cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
                Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);


                PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                alarmintent,0);
                int HELLO_ID=1;
                // Get the AlarmManager service
                HELLO_ID++;
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                Log.d("Alarm Set","day = "+dp.getDayOfMonth()+" month = "+(dp.getMonth()+1)+" year = "+dp.getYear()+" hours "+tp.getCurrentHour()+" minutes = "+tp.getCurrentMinute());
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
    }
```

AlarmReciever.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // When our Alaram time is triggered , this method will be excuted (onReceive)
     // We're invoking a service in this method which shows Notification to the User
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
      context.startService(myIntent);



}
};
```

NotificationService.java

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

private NotificationManager mManager;
Notification notification;
private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    // Getting Notification Service
    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(
                    this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    /*
     * When the user taps the notification we have to show the Home Screen
     * of our App, this job can be done with the help of the following
     * Intent.
     */
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), DecidedCase.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(),NOTIFICATION_ID, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    //notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        //  "Trying out Alarm", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentTitle("ScheduLAWyer")
                    .setContentText("You've got a notification")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(8)
                    .setTicker("A case has to be viewed").build();
                    //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Launch app",pendingNotificationIntent)
                    //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Cancel",pendingNotificationIntent).build();

    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    //PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        //  this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
            //PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



    /*notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
            "sudduLAWyer", "Trying out Alarm Manager",
            pendingNotificationIntent);*/
    //notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    //notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.ledARGB = 0xFFFFA500;
    notification.ledOnMS = 800;
    notification.ledOffMS = 1000;

    mManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, notification);
    Log.d("NOTIFICATION","Notficiation Set");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mManager.cancel(0);
}

}
```

Comment: `if(item.getTitle()=="Add Reminder")` should be `if("Add Reminder".equals(item.getTitle())`  (this is java not js)

Comment: hmmm that's right, my bad. Switching between WorkLight and SDK sometimes fumbles me.

Comment: it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because of the alarm. `Notification` itself cannot add it one more time if you call `setAutoCancel(true)`.

You can try

`a.cancel(sender)` in `onReceive` of `AlarmReceiver` of yours. 
You will have to recreate that sender object to cancel it.

Comment: Hmmm that probably seem to be the answer but how to implement it? `AlarmManager.cancel()` method needs a pending intent as a parameter which should match the one used to create the Alarm. Could you please look at the code and tell me how to make it ?

Comment: You can create the intent just like you create above.  Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), DecidedCase.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(),NOTIFICATION_ID, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not use service to just send `notification` , I think it would be better if you write some `Util` function and move the code of `service` `onStart` to Util method.

If you requirement needs service only then I suggest you to use [IntentServive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)